# How to use localization in Razor Class Library in Asp.Net Core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I have tried to create the Razor Class Library with Asp.Net Core in following project structure:

[image]

I have used in my web application these settings for localization in `Startup` class:

```
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                    .AddViewLocalization(
                        LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
                        opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
                    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

                services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
                    opts =>
                    {
                        var supportedCultures = new[]
                        {
                            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                            new CultureInfo("en")
                        };

                        opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
                        opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                        opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                    });

....

var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
```

In `Index.cshtml`:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer


<h1>@Localizer["Title"]</h1>
```

Unfortunately, the result is only string "Title". I can't load these resx files from Razor Class Library.

How can I use the localization in Razor Class Library like above?

**UPDATE**: This is very similiar use case - https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/328 - that provides some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have forgotten to configure localization correctly using `AddLocalization`

Using details provided from documentation

Reference [Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

> ### Configure localization
>
> Localization is configured in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"); //<<< This is required

services
    .AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

`AddLocalization` Adds the localization services to the services container. The code above also sets the resources path to "Resources".

`AddViewLocalization` Adds support for localized view files.

`AddDataAnnotationsLocalization` Adds support for localized `DataAnnotations` validation messages through `IStringLocalizer` abstractions.

> ### Localization middleware
>
> The current culture on a request is set in the localization Middleware. The localization middleware is enabled in the `Configure` method. The localization middleware must be configured before any middleware which might check the request culture (for example, `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()`).

```
var supportedCultures = new[] {
    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    new CultureInfo("en")
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
    // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    // UI strings that we have localized.
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});

//...other middleware

app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

The path to the resource file shown in the example image follows the path naming convention given that
you are using the `ResourcesPath` option which was set to *"Resources"*. This should allow the view to find the resource file in the relative path to the "Resources" folder.

An alternative is to not use the `ResourcesPath` option, and place the *.resx* file in the same folder as the view, following the naming convention of course.

Base on additional details provided it was indicated that the UI project would be packaged as a nuget package.

Then have the resources files packaged into the nuget package and have them unpacked to the resources folder of the target project when when installed.

The resources need to be in the site root to be available to the view, so you then need to reference all the files in your `.nuspec`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
    <metadata>...
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <!-- Add all resource files -->
        <file src="Resources\**\*.resx" target="content\Resources" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Reference [Creating NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package)

Comment: I have tried your code snippets, but unfourtunetly it doesn't work. I have two projects - first project is with web app and second with razor ui where is folder with "resources". I have referenced razor UI to web app project where I used your settings. Is it problem that resources are with razor ui assembly that is referenced to web project?

Comment: @Jenan Resources (*.resx*) need to live in the root project base to be accessible. So that would mean they need to be in the web project.

Comment: @Jenan I thought you were using a RazorPages project not just referencing razor pages from another project. That will cause problem when referencing resource files.

Comment: My idea is create a separate DLL with UI - that's provides new razor class library, but the problem is sharing the resource files. How to solve it? Sharing the resx files with UI razor class library?

Comment: Just to test try having the resources in the root project and keep the views in the separate library and see if it works.

Comment: That's works, resx files in web project and referenced the razor class library but I want to put resx files in razor class library because I want to publish the UI with localization as a nuget package. :-)

Comment: @Jenan Then have the resources files in the nuget package and have it unpack to the resources folder when referenced by a project. You have already seen that it will work. That is how the framework works with resource files.

Comment: @Jenan I have to step out for a bit. I'll check in when I get back later to see how it goes.

Comment: What do you mean with unpack the resources? Do you have some sample for that? I'll be very happy for any point for this idea.

Comment: @Jenan check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort to help with issue. This is similiar use case - https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/328

Comment: @Jenan Do you have a working sample as per answer? Can you please share?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried the accepted answer and based on the comments, it seems the OP didn't get it to work.  I implemented a pattern similar to the View/Page locator pattern that MVC/Razor Pages uses namely, that resources can be provided in a RCL or separate assembly and use `ViewLocalizer` and it'll just find the matching resource string from the highest precedence resource.  You can read my implementation and see if it might work for you.

https://terryaney.wordpress.com/2021/01/04/migrating-to-net-core-overridable-localization-in-razor-class-libraries/